# Listener duplication in Addon SDK panel

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am using a panel called by widget to take a snapshot of storage and display it in a table. BUt there appears to be some duplication on the markup being done.

Basically I have one storage item for testing purposes and a couple of settings like switches. Every time I click on the widget to open it the storage item gets duplicated on the page. I can understand that as the panel does not reload on show/hide.

The main issue is that I have a normal jQuery click event to send some data back to storage and this also seems to get duplicated. If I open and close the panel 6 times I get six events firing from one click.

This says to me that each reload is creating more listeners but I cannot find anything to tell me how to remove the listeners correctly.. See example

**Content script**

```
testPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("test.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("test.js")],
    onShow: function() {
        testPanel.port.emit("Loaded")
        testPanel.port.on("clicked", function(){
            console.log('received click')
        });
    }
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "my-widget",
    label: "My Widget",
    panel: testPanel,
        content: "Click here"
});
```

**test.js**

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    self.port.emit("clicked");
});

self.port.on("Loaded", function() {
    $(".wrapper").append('<div>New element</div>');
});
```

**Console Output**

```
info: test_addon: Script loaded
info: test_addon: clicked
info: test_addon: received click
info: test_addon: clicked
info: test_addon: received click
info: test_addon: received click
info: test_addon: clicked
info: test_addon: received click
info: test_addon: received click
info: test_addon: received click
```

Anyone had similar issues?

**Problem solved**

Usage of `removeListener()` is not 100% clear but by using a global function instead of an anonymous one you can remove the event listener `onHide`. It will then create a new instance `onShow` but the old one has been removed. Phew!

**Content script**

```
function showClick() {
    console.log('received click')
}
testPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("test.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("test.js")],
    onShow: function() {
        testPanel.port.emit("Loaded");
        testPanel.port.on("clicked", showClick);
    },
    onHide: function() {
        testPanel.port.removeListener('clicked', showClick);
    }
});
```

Comment: IMHO `el.addEventListener` add every time new listener, so your addon received many times `click` event. Maybe `.once('click', ...);` will help?

Comment: I just sovled the problem, each time the panel shows a new listener is created (2,3,4,5 etc..). The documentation is not clear on usage but I needed to close the listener on hide. panel.port.removeListener('clicked', clickFunction); Does what it should do and prevents the re-spawning of listeners.

Comment: There is no mention of using port to with the removeListener function in this doc but without it is doesn't work. [Creating event targets](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.13/dev-guide/tutorials/event-targets.html)

Comment: I can't thin of a use for once in my code as it is only allowed once, not loaded once. I seem to have big problems with listeners being recreated but can't find any documentation to corroborate this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you solved the problem but generally you don't want to create listeners in the `onShow` method.  I'd recommend you create your listener outside of the `onShow` method and if you need to you can use the `isShowing` property to check if the panel is open when you receive the event.  Now you just have a single listener for the life of the panel.

```
function showClick() {
    console.log('received click')
}
testPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: data.url("test.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("test.js")],
    onShow: function() {
        testPanel.port.emit("Loaded");
    },
    onHide: function() {

    }
});
testPanel.port.on("clicked", function() {
  if (testPanel.isShowing) {
    console.log('received click');
  }
});
```

Comment: I am always up for making my code cleaner and I'll work this in to the add-on. The sdk does not provide a use-case for this value which is a bit frustrating. If duplicate workers are an issue it should be covered in the docs really but there is nothing! I have a few duplicate worker problems which I am taking a hatchet to :o. 
Thanks C.